# How do I hide file extensions in a command prompt /dir output?

Tags: windows, command-line

What I want to do seems very simple:
I have a folder in Windows containing items of various types including PDF files, TXT files, and subdirectories. I am writing a one line .bat file to pull ONLY the PDF file names into a new text file.

So far this is what I have in the .bat:

```
dir *.pdf /b > PDF_LIST.txt
```

This gives the following output in a PDF_LIST.txt file:

```
A.pdf
B.pdf
C.pdf
```

I would like to drop the ".pdf" portion of each line in the txt file, since I obviously know already that each file is in PDF format by the *.pdf parameter in my dir statement.

This would just make it easier for me to copy/paste all the file names directly from the text file into a word document for a transmittal I'm sending to my customer. If you can suggest a better or easier way to get the file list without using a batch file that would also would be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your script:

```
for %%i in (*.pdf) do @echo %%~ni >> PDF_LIST.txt
```

Comment: Whoa that blows my mind (never really worked with command line). Ok I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: See `help for` to have some additional cranial stimulation.

Comment: I corrected (what I think was) your typo in the code and ran this command: for %%i in (*.pdf) do @echo %%~ni >> PDF_LIST.txt I'm getting the response "%%i was unexpected at this time" and no other output.

Comment: @NoCatharsis: Sorry about the typo. At the command line just use single `%`. Use `%%` in your batch file.

Comment: Cool, works like a charm - thanks a lot for the quick help.

Comment: guru. love this solution

Answer (score 0):

Most text editors (including notepad) have find and replace. Just use it to find all ".pdf" and replace it with "". Done :)

You can set this as macro in word, as well.

Comment: Yes, I use Notepad++ to do this right now - however I was just wondering if there was a way to cut out one more step by writing it into a script.