# Windows 10 Command Prompt - List all files and folders inside a directory without displaying file extensions

Tags: windows-10, command-line, file-extension, dir

I've been using **dir /b** to display all files and folders in a directory but it includes the file extension for every file in a directory. What is the command for displaying all files without including their extension?

**Example:**

A entered dir /b inside a directory and it displays the following:

Avengers Endgame (2019).mp4 
Thor Ragnarok (2017).mp4 
....................

**What I want is this:**

Avengers Endgame (2019) 
Thor Ragnarok (2017)

To be displayed in command prompt without including their file extensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide file extensions in a command prompt /dir output?](https://superuser.com/questions/223156/how-do-i-hide-file-extensions-in-a-command-prompt-dir-output) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962981/how-to-show-only-filenames-without-extensions-using-dir-command

Comment: Is PowerShell an option? Check out `Get-ChildIem | select Basename` (short version `(gci).Basename'`) or `gci | format-wide -Property Basename -Column 3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install any updates on clean Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/1120602/cannot-install-any-updates-on-clean-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command prompt you can use something like this:

```
for %a in (*) do @echo %~na
```

To include Folders in the result:

`dir /ad /b & For %a in (*) do @echo %~na`

But at some point it might be difficult to tell the difference between a folder and a file so maybe you may want to do something like this:

`echo. & echo Folders: & echo. & dir /ad /b & echo. & echo Files: & echo. & For %a in (*) do @echo %~na`

This would result in something like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you! But how do I include the folders in the list?

Comment: Just edited the answer...